# Google Sheet Auto Email Trigger

Tags: triggers

I am looking for someone to help me out. I have a team of agents, i am tracking performance and I want to write a code that allows me to send an email out when the average for the week is below the metric. The google sheets get updated daily and I understand some code but looking to understand more so I can edit and manipulate it in the future as needs change. I also need it to look at all cells with data and not just specific ranges as the ranges change daily because of new data.
Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a canevas

```
function specialOnEdit(e){
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var cel = e.source.getActiveRange();
  if (sheet.getName()=='Sheet 1' && (cel.getColumn()==22 || cel.getColumn()==25)){
    var i = cel.getRow()
    if (sheet.getRange('V'+i).getValue()=='Done' && sheet.getRange('Y'+i).getValue()=='Ready' && sheet.getRange('Z'+i).getValue()!='EMAIL OK' ){
      GmailApp.sendEmail(sheet.getRange('X'+i).getValue(), sheet.getRange('A'+i).getValue(), 'Done') ;
      sheet.getRange('Z'+i).setValue('EMAIL OK')
      Browser.msgBox('Email sent')
    }
  }
}
```

but you should now give us a project